# TortoiseHG: how to show count of revisions that match current filter?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

In TortoiseHG, how can I show the count of revisions that match my current filter?

Comment: Can whoever downvoted this please explain why?  I don't understand what about this question was objectionable.  It was a specific, concise question.

Comment: -1, as written in tooltip "This question doesn't show any research effort..." and in *this case* - it's true

Comment: That is an asinine rule.  I looked at the View menu options, looked at the help files, and googled for various related search terms.  How would explaining my failed research help anyone answer such a simple question?  Someone was likely to know the answer off the top of their head.  How would detailing my failed research help people viewing the page for an already accepted answer?  All it would do is add useless verbiage.  "lack of original research" should only apply to things that are easily google-able, or to things that are complex enough such that partial research would be beneficial.

Comment: Also, parsing that rule, if I had typed the exact same question followed by the following quoted text, I shouldn't have be downvoted: "I researched by reading poetry by Ovid, but couldn't find any answers there". The question itself would be just as clear and useful, and I'd have shown research effort (albeit useless research, but the rule doesn't require that research be useful). Blindly following ridiculous rules is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

- `View` - `Filter Toolbar` (see `1`)
- Write revset or open Anvanced Query Editor (see `2`) and write final revset in it
- Status-bar of Anvanced Query Editor show amount of filtered changesets in real time (see `3`)

[image: Filter toolbar and editor]

Comment: I'd prefer to have the count visible directly in the main TortoiseHG window.  Is there any way to do that?  Thanks.

Comment: @XDR - support https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/3887/counter-of-filtered-changeset